# Create a method as a Katalon Keyword to return a DOB, calculated to make the DOB always a day under 18 yrs old to use as input value

Tags: date, groovy, keyword, katalon

Hi guys :) pls can someone help me - I'm looking to create a method which uses todays date to calculate a DOB which is returned as an input value. This is to test rules validation and the DOB needs to always be that its the day before the 18th birthday

Ideally this would be created as a keyword in Katalon / Groovy

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you done something yourself?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.